# Some of the item change it's content in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I' setting up my recyclerview with a list of prodcuts, some of its items change its content when I scroll up/ down.

I have debug my code but list of product does not change. It appears only in this recyclerview.

Here is Visual for my problem.

[Gif to show my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfFJw.gif)

Here is Adapter code

```
@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    productItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
    return new ProductViewHolder(productItemBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product product = mProductList.get(position);
    holder.bindHolder(product);
}



public void setData(List<Product> productList) {

    mProductList = productList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ProductViewHolder(@NonNull ProductItemBinding productItemBinding) {
        super(productItemBinding.getRoot());
    }

    void bindHolder(Product product) {
        productItemBinding.setProducts(product);
        productItemBinding.setAdapter(ProductAdapter.this);
        productItemBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

Here is my call to adapter

```
    productViewModel.getActionProducts("sale", parameter).observe(this, productsContainer -> {

        productsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        productsArrayList = actionProductsContainer.getData().getProducts();

        activityProductListingBinding.rvProducts.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(this, this);
        activityProductListingBinding.rvProducts.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
        productsAdapter.setData(productsArrayList);

        activityProductListingBinding.pbLoadingActionProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    });
```

Here is my XML for recyclerview.

```
<data>

    <!--<import type="com.workout.height.helper.AppUtils" />-->

    <variable
        name="products"
        type="com.lalaland.ecommerce.data.models.products.Product" />

    <variable
        name="adapter"
        type="com.lalaland.ecommerce.adapters.ProductAdapter" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/iv_product"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:setProductImage="@{products.primaryImage}" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/info_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_product">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{products.brandName}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_product_detail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@{products.quantity}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_product_current_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{products.salePrice}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/us_zipcodes" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_product_pre_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{products.actualPrice}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/us_zipcodes" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is Custom binding to load image

```
@BindingAdapter("setProductImage")
public static void setImageFromServer(ImageView imageView, String imageName) {

    String imageSrc = PRODUCT_STORAGE_BASE_URL.concat(imageName);
    Glide
            .with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(imageSrc)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
            .fitCenter()
            .apply(RequestOptions.centerInsideTransform())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: FYI: recyclerview reuse the view and states will remain when scroll. so you have reset it in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: Why are you changing the adapter and layout manager of your recyclerview every time the data updates? You should set up the list once (when the view is created) and just update its items whenever necessary via `productsAdapter.setData()`. Constantly setting the adapter and layout manager of the list is pretty weird.

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas I'm in initial phase of application and some of the feature of app is not sure so I;m gonna sure refactor my code :) , but thanks for your suggestion